# MS Access: Concatenate recordset with different separators based on number of records

Tags: ms-access, vba

How do I concatenate a recordset and have separators based on the number of records?  No separator for one record, “ and “ for two records, and commas between more than two records with “, and” before the last record.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result. Use http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Comment: I have a concatenate function that results in a numbered list:
1) Peter
2) Paul
3) Mary
4) Joseph
I want the result to be in sentence format such as, “Peter, Paul, Mary, and Joseph.”  I need the function to properly punctuate the sentence based on the number of records.
If record set has only one name the result would be “Peter”
If record set has two names the result would be “Peter and Paul”
If record set has more than two names the result would be “Peter, Paul, Mary, and Joseph.”

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
Dim test() As String
Dim arraySize As Integer
Dim arrayCounter As Integer
Dim rec as RecordSet

Set rec = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT MyField FROM MyTable")

'I was always told that MoveFirst/MoveLast gave the most 
'  accurate count of records
rec.MoveFirst
rec.MoveLast
arraysize = rec.RecordCount

'reDim the array, now that you know the size
reDim test(arraySize)

'Fill the array
For i = 0 to arraysize - 1
  test(i) = rec(0)
next I

'Set up the text string
MyText = ""

For j =  0 to arraysize - 1
  If (j - 1) = arraysize Then
    MyText = MyText & " and " & test(j)
  else
    MyText = MyText & ", " & test(j)
  End If
Next j

'Trim off the first comma
MyFinalText = Trim(Right(MyText, Len(MyText) - 2))
```